# Call hotkey only once with react-hotkeys-hook

Tags: reactjs, hotkeys

I have 2 hotkeys in my app, `1` and `2`. If I press `1` release and then `2`, it's fine. But if I press both at the same time, it doesn't increment as expected when I release both at the same time.

My expectation is that if I press 1 and 2, and then release both, I should have both incrementing by 1. But it doesn't. I checked the API and tried some different options but it always seems to increment 2 in one of the cases.

```js
import { useHotkeys } from 'react-hotkeys-hook';

export default function App() {
  const [cnt1, set1] = React.useState(0);
  const [cnt2, set2] = React.useState(0);

  useHotkeys('1', () => set1((v) => v + 1), { keyup: true });
  useHotkeys('2', () => set2((v) => v + 1), { keyup: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{cnt1}</div>
      <div>{cnt2}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

A running example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6mbnsa?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Is there a special condition you want to ignore it? You could check the time difference between those 2

Comment: I don't think so. The order could be the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried quite some ways to prevent this, found a single, not so great solution I thought I'd share.

---

There seems to be a [`isHotkeyPressed` hook](https://react-hotkeys-hook.vercel.app/docs/documentation/is-hotkey-pressed) that can be used in the second callback to check if the other hotkey is active:

```
useHotkeys('2', () => {
    if (!isHotkeyPressed('1')) {
        set2((v) => v + 1);
    }
}, { keyup: true });
```

---

You could combine both hotkeys hooks into a single one (you can pass multiple keys comma separated) to make the `isHotkeyPressed` on the other key more dynamic.

Comment: This is working, thanks! But it seems like a bug right? The keyup activates all the hotkeys and not only the ones selected. I press both numbers, release 1 and both increment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a mistake copying @0stone0 answer and inadvertently made it work. I'm still confused how this is working, but it even works if I have 4 numbers.

Notice it only increments if the key I'm letting go up is not pressed.

```js
  useHotkeys(
    '1',
    () => {
      if (!isHotkeyPressed('1')) {
        set1((v) => v + 1);
      }
    },
    {
      keyup: true,
    }
  );
  useHotkeys(
    '2',
    () => {
      if (!isHotkeyPressed('2')) {
        set2((v) => v + 1);
      }
    },
    {
      keyup: true,
    }
  );
```

Comment: And I can't make it work using multiple keys...